# Cannot deploy basic OpenWhisk action onto Kubernetes running with Minikube

Tags: macos, kubernetes, minikube, openwhisk

I am trying to setup a simple POC of Apache OpenWhisk serverless framework running on Kubernetes.  I am using MacOS with Minikube.  Here are the specs:

```
Kubernetes: v1.20.2
Minikube: v1.17.0
Docker: 20.10.0-rc1, 4.26GB allocated
```

Here are the setup steps for Minikube:

```
$ minikube start --cpus 2 --memory 4096 --kubernetes-version=v1.20.2
$ minikube ssh -- sudo ip link set docker0 promisc on
$ kubectl create namespace openwhisk
$ kubectl label nodes --all openwhisk-role=invoker
```

Install OpenWhisk using Helm:

```
$ helm install owdev ./helm/openwhisk -n openwhisk --create-namespace -f mycluster.yaml
```

Configure Whisk CLI:

```
$ wsk property set --apihost 192.168.49.2:31001
$ wsk property set --auth 23bc46b1-71f6-4ed5-8c54-816aa4f8c502:123zO3xZCLrMN6v2BKK1dXYFpXlPkccOFqm12CdAsMgRU4VrNZ9lyGVCGuMDGIwP
```

The `192.168.49.2` IP address of Minikube was confirmed by typing:

```
$ minikube ip
```

Here is my `mycluster.yaml` file:

```
whisk:
  ingress:
    type: NodePort
    apiHostName: 192.168.49.2
    apiHostPort: 31001

nginx:
  httpsNodePort: 31001
```

I checked the health of my OpenWhisk setup:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n openwhisk
NAME                                                          READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
owdev-alarmprovider-5b86cb64ff-q86nj                          1/1     Running     0          137m
owdev-apigateway-bccbbcd67-7q2r8                              1/1     Running     0          137m
owdev-controller-0                                            1/1     Running     13         137m
owdev-couchdb-584676b956-7pxtc                                1/1     Running     0          137m
owdev-gen-certs-7227t                                         0/1     Completed   0          137m
owdev-init-couchdb-g6vhb                                      0/1     Completed   0          137m
owdev-install-packages-sg2f4                                  1/1     Running     0          137m
owdev-invoker-0                                               1/1     Running     1          137m
owdev-kafka-0                                                 1/1     Running     0          137m
owdev-kafkaprovider-5574d4bf5f-vvdb9                          1/1     Running     0          137m
owdev-nginx-86749d59cb-mxxrt                                  1/1     Running     0          137m
owdev-redis-d65649c5b-vd8d4                                   1/1     Running     0          137m
owdev-wskadmin                                                1/1     Running     0          137m
owdev-zookeeper-0                                             1/1     Running     0          137m
wskowdev-invoker-00-13-prewarm-nodejs10                       1/1     Running     0          116m
wskowdev-invoker-00-14-prewarm-nodejs10                       1/1     Running     0          116m
wskowdev-invoker-00-15-whisksystem-invokerhealthtestaction0   1/1     Running     0          112m
```

Finally, I created a simple hello world action following [these instructions taken directly from the OpenWhisk documentation](https://openwhisk.apache.org/documentation.html#actions-nodejs).  When I try to test the action, I get a network timeout:

```
$ wsk action create helloJS hello.js
```

> error: Unable to create action 'helloJS': Put "https://192.168.49.2:31001/api/v1/namespaces/_/actions/helloJS?overwrite=false": dial tcp 192.168.49.2:31001: i/o timeout

I tried turning on debug mode with the `-d` switch, but could not make much of what feedback I am seeing.

My feeling is that there is either a bug at work here, or perhaps Minikube on Mac was never intended to be fully supported on OpenWhisk.

Can anyone suggest what I might try to get this setup and action working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We stopped maintaining OpenWhisk for Minikube a while ago.  With the availability of a full-fledged Kubernetes cluster built-in to Docker Desktop on MacOS and Windows and `kind` (https://kind.sigs.k8s.io) being available on all of our platforms supporting Minikube was more work than it was worth.

Comment: Dave, thanks for these comments.  Can you point me to any resource outlining what sort of Kubernetes deployment one would need to work with the latest version of OpenWhisk?

Comment: We list some options in the main README: https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube#kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the pod (starting with the name *owdev-install-packages-*) packages completes.
This may take some time, after that it should work.